# Use minimum number of half adders for the boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I got this question in my exam, and I cannot find the answer to it. My professor also didn't provide a clear solution. Can someone please help me in this?

> Design the expression F(A,B,C,D)=AB' + AC' + DC + AD using only half adders. Do it in minimum number of half adders.

My try at the solution-
I converted it into minimal SOP form, which I got is AB' + AC' + CD. I made each complemented literal by passing 1 and the literal to the half adder which gives me both kinds. Then I made the minterms using AND in half adder and then I got stuck how to OR them all together.

Comment: You need to tell us how much you do understand about the question. Show us a significant amount of your own work.

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Comment: You only have AND and XOR pairs to work with. You have to use both in each instantiation (or waste something, regardless.) You are looking for the minimum number of ***pairs***. Two inputs, two outputs. Don't ever forget that fact. How would you attempt to approach such a "minimization?" (It is a very good exam question.) Keep track of the patterns involved. And don't forget you only have, in the end, one output.

Comment: I tried I got 10 half adders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the expression with a brute force:

[image]

[image]

As we see the result of the function almost always equal to A except two cases:

1. C=1 and D=1 (the result is 1)
2. B=1 and C=1 and D=0 (the result is 0)

So we can write a new expression F=(A+CD)(BCD')'.

Now count half-adders:

1. CD - 1 half-adder
2. A+CD - 2 half-adders (OR = two half adders)
3. BC - 1 half-adder
4. D' - 1 half-adder (NOT = one half adder, one input is tie to 1)
5. BC and D' - 1 half-adder
6. (BCD')' - 1 half-adder
7. (A+CD)(BCD')'- 1 half-adder

Total: 8 half-adders